# Publicar un texto editable en php html5

Tags: php, javascript, html5, plugin

estoy desarrollando una pagina, para que el usuario, publique cierta informacion en un texto, mi duda es si existe algun plugin que me de este tipo de herramientas antes de que publique.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo recomiendo utilizar [quill](/questions/tagged/quill):

A continuación te dejo el demo que tienen el sitio:

```js
  var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
    theme: 'snow'
  });
```

```html
<!-- Include stylesheet -->
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Create the editor container -->
<div id="editor">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Some initial <strong>bold</strong> text</p>
  <p><br></p>
</div>

<!-- Include the Quill library -->
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
```

Comment: Encontre el ckeditor previamente, de todas formas gracias.